# Background image disappearing on Safari

Tags: css, mobile

I have a little problem: my website is functioning properly on all my desktop browsers (even in "mobile mode" with Chrome Developer Tools), but when I try to see it on my phone (iPhone 5s), the background image disappears.

I found out that "height" applied on any container div was the problem. When I try to apply any height other that auto or 100%, it happens.

Here is the link: http://adrideco.com/prp/

And the code (I put off script and other useless panels)

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <div id="ext" class="container">
        <img src="logo.png" class="logo" />
        <img src="logo-dark.png" class="logo logomenu" />
        <div class="extender">
            <div class="panel menu">
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="content">
                        <a id="index" onclick="link(event, 'index')" href="#">Accueil</a>
                        <a id="portfolio" onclick="link(event, 'portfolio')" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <a id="contact" onclick="link(event, 'contact')" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--
                -->
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1> Développeur, designer, entrepreneur </h1>
                        <img class="profil" src="profil.jpg"/>
                        <p>
                        Je suis dans le milieu du développement web et du design depuis maintenant 2 ans, et je propose mes services en tant que developpeur et designer freelance.<br />
                        Si tu veux voir mes précédents projets, ils sont disponibles sur mon <a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a><br /><br />

                        Un peu d'expérience c'est bien, mais un diplôme ça l'est aussi. Je prépare une certification de Chargé de production web et digital à Efficom dans le but de décrocher un master si je ne perce pas avant !<br /><br />
                        Afin d'approfondir mes connaissances du travail en entreprise après avoir effectué un bref stage d'un mois et demi, je recherche une entreprise pour m'accueillir en tant qu'alternant dès la rentré 2018.<br />
                        Si mon profil t'intéresse, <a href="portfolio.php">contact moi</a> !
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> [...]
```

SCSS

```
.container {
width: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
// height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
background-position: 20% 0%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url('bg.png');

.panel {
        display: inline-block;
        width: calc(100% / 4);
        height: 100vh;          <- This is ruining
        vertical-align: top;

        .block{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center; [...]
```

Thank you all !

edit:

The background-color applied on my white panel is also responsible, when I delete it, it works, but I really need this background !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution, not that good to be honest but at least they background is there...

Instead of putting a background-color on my panel I put a linear gradient to the large container:

```
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 240, 240), rgb(240, 240, 240) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```